# Facebook API does not return userid

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
  require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
 $config = array();
  $config['appId'] = '109181812948600';
  $config['secret'] = 'edflmlkmlkmlkmlkmlk7079e9d5884';
  $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $uid = $facebook->getUser();
  echo $uid;
```

Returning userid as 0. i just want to access my photos which i uploaded in the FB.

Answer (score 0):

You have to approve your app from your profile. You can get URL with this:

```
header("Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_photos')));
die();
```

After that you'll probably need to get access token from

```
$tokenURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
      . $config['appId'] . "&redirect_uri=" . 'your_redirect_url'
      . "&client_secret=" . $config['secret']
      . "&code=" . $_GET["code"] . "&display=popup";
```

You can store this token and reuse it after, just don't forget to recreate it every 59 days.

Comment: how to approve, where i go and approve, i am new to this facebook

Comment: facebook page will show up asking you to approve. You just click yes, and it redirect's you back to your redirect URL with code value.

Comment: Just like when you access any other app on facebook, it asks you do you wanna approve it or not.

Comment: its already approved know, so that i got this appid and seckey

Comment: still i am not able to understand how to fetch the photos from FB. its too complicated for me

Comment: You get AppID and secret when you create app on FB. Then you visit this page $facebook->getLoginUrl() and you'll get new code which you use to fetch token. And then you use that token with every request for posting/getting images. I haven't test it, maybe you don't need this token for public photos, put for posting photos you do need it.